# Filter multidimensional array that contains a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array...

```
var families = [
  {
    family:"Jones",
    kids: [
      {name:"Kelly", gender:'female'},
      {name:"Mike", gender:'male'},
      {name:"Bill", gender:'male'}
    ]
  },{
    family:"Smiths",
    kids: [
      {name:"Roger", gender:'male'}
    ]
  }
]
```

...that I need filter through and sort out familys by gender. So if I search for 'female' I want an array of families that contain females in their family. Regardless if there is a male in the family. So in the above code, if I search for female, only one family would return. But if I searched by male, 2 families would return.

My try looks like this:

```
var filter = 'female';
filteredList = families.filter(function (family) {
  return family.kids.filter(function (kid) {
    return kid.gender.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
  })
})
```

Am I not returning it properly?

Comment: is it possible that `kids` could have `kids` of their own? are you interested in a recursive solution?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but for my use that that wouldn't be needed. Appreciate the foresight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use `filter` and `some` like so:

```js
var families=[{family:"Jones",kids:[{name:"Kelly",gender:'female'},{name:"Mike",gender:'male'},{name:"Bill",gender:'male'}]},{family:"Smiths",kids:[{name:"Roger",gender:'male'}]}];
var filter = "female";
const res = families.filter(({ kids }) => kids.some(({ gender }) => gender == filter));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var families=[{family:"Jones",kids:[{name:"Kelly",gender:'female'},{name:"Mike",gender:'male'},{name:"Bill",gender:'male'}]},{family:"Smiths",kids:[{name:"Roger",gender:'male'}]}];
var filter = "female";
var res = families.filter(function(family) {
  return family.kids.some(function(kid) {
    return kid.gender == filter;
  })
});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: That's no problem @user3612986 - if my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically there except for one small detail: your inner filter returns an empty array to the outer filter, which is always evaluated as true. Add `.length` to the inner array to make empty arrays falsey:

```js
var families = [ { family:"Jones", kids: [ {name:"Kelly", gender:'female'}, {name:"Mike", gender:'male'}, {name:"Bill", gender:'male'} ] },{ family:"Smiths", kids: [ {name:"Roger", gender:'male'} ] } ];

var filter = 'female';
filteredList = families.filter(function (family) {
  return family.kids.filter(function (kid) {
    return kid.gender.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
  }).length
  //^^^^^^^
});

console.log(filteredList);
```

Comment: I would have never figured that out. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` and `some`. `forEach` will be used to iterate over the array and use `some` to find if any object in `kids` have the required gender.

```js
var families = [{
  family: "Jones",
  kids: [{
      name: "Kelly",
      gender: 'female'
    },
    {
      name: "Mike",
      gender: 'male'
    },
    {
      name: "Bill",
      gender: 'male'
    }
  ]
}, {
  family: "Smiths",
  kids: [{
    name: "Roger",
    gender: 'male'
  }]
}];


let filteredData = function(arr, gender) {
  let filteredFamily = [];
  arr.forEach(function(elem) {
    let ifHasGender = elem.kids.some(function(item) {
      return item.gender === gender
    })
    if (ifHasGender) {
      filteredFamily.push(elem)
    }
  })

  return filteredFamily;
}

console.log(filteredData(families, 'female'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That does work! But I was hoping to get around a forEach.

Comment: so odd to see you using `.some` but then writing your own filter using `.forEach` instead of using `.filter` - you even called the variable *filtered*...